# WPF DataGridTextColumn Can't type point for float data

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I had a WPF DataGrid and use DataGridTextColumn Binding to a Collection. The items in Collection had some float property.

When my program launched, I modify the value of float property in DataGrid, if I type a integer value, it works well. But if I type char . for a float value, char . can't be typed. I had to type all the numbers first, and then jump to the . position to type char . to finish my input.

So how can I type . in my situation?

Thanks.

Comment: post your code,

you probably have a converter or a validator to int and not to float

Comment: Or it could be a problem with localization. Some countries use . (period) as the decimal separator, and some use , (comma) as the separator. Try both?

Answer (score 3):

Also met the same problem.

For my case, it is due to the data binding options.

I changed from `*.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;`  to `*.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;`.

Then it can type `float` number directly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with Localization.
Try changing the Culture settings of your thread to check out if this could be the problem:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

you can double-check the settings if you are unsure in which Culture you are running by going to `Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region` or running the following code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Debug.WriteLine("decimal: " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
Debug.WriteLine("thousand: " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer my question. After check my Localization settings, My PC's setting is:" Decimal symbol: . " The setting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regular Expression Validation in Binding.

```
<Validator:RegexValidationRule x:Key="DecimalValidatorFor3Digits"
    RegularExpression="^\d{0,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$"
    ErrorMessage="The field must contain only numbers with max 3 integers and 2 decimals" />
```

Thanks

Ck Nitin (TinTin)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer my question. Can I use StringFormat in Binding to resolve my problem? There's only ValidatesOnDataErrors,ValidatesOnExceptions,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors and StringFormat could used in DataGridTextColumn.Binding.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because your datagridcolumn is bound to your class member with decimal datatype, e.g.

```
public class Product : ModelBase
{
    decimal _price = 0;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set { _price = value; OnPropertyChanged("Price"); }
    }
}
```

and the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. One way to do get rid of it is to change the property to string type, and manipulate the string like below:

```
string _price = "0.00";
    public string Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set 
        {
            string s = value;
            decimal d = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(value, out d))
                _price = s;
            else
                _price = s.Substring(0, s.Length == 0 ? 0 : s.Length - 1);
            OnPropertyChanged("Price"); 
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps