# WPF DataGrid - DataGridTextColumn decimal/double/float input with PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm having trouble with decimal (double/float) inputs in DataGridTextColumn with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

(1) I have searched several sites and many suggest to change this to LostFocus. Im not very keen on this implementation cause the behaviour with PropertyChanged is what I require. Unless there is a way to get the same result with LostFocus??

I have read the following  articles on stackoverflow -
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628058/wpf-datagrid-datagridtextcolumn-does-not-allow-decimal), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985650/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-binding-doesnt-accept-decimals), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949778/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-cant-type-point-for-float-data), [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600842/bind-textbox-to-float-value-unable-to-input-dot-comma), [Link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506323/difference-between-tostringn2-and-tostring0-00) & [Link 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909394/how-to-allow-only-positive-decimal-value-in-wpf-datagridtextcolumn)

(2) Using `Binding="{Binding StringFormat=N2}"`or its variation has a very annoying behavior as described in the comments in [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600842/bind-textbox-to-float-value-unable-to-input-dot-comma).

(3) The other method is to allow string input and parse it as double in the back end. This is fine-ish, and I'm holding onto it as a last resort solution only.

(4) Lastly in the same [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600842/bind-textbox-to-float-value-unable-to-input-dot-comma), a solution mentioned by xmedeko -  `System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;` for .NET 4.5 or later only.

I do have the newer version but not sure how/where to implement this line of code. Or if there's a way to turn this property false in the XAML itself? Any help is greatly appreciated. Unable to reply as a comment on that link due to my reputation level.

If there is a any other neater way while keeping the behavior similar to PropertyChanged, would be very helpful.

**CODE**
XAML -   `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding Path=Rate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="90"/>`

cs -

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}

public double Rate
{
   get { return rate; }
   set { rate = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Rate"); }
}
```

The code is actually very simple. This is displayed on a datagrid. The DataGridTextColumn does not accept decimal values and this correctly noted by Chevul Ervin in [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985650/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-binding-doesnt-accept-decimals) -

> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged reevalutes the text on every
>   keystroke. A number that ends in a decimal point is invalid. Change
>   the UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus (same as removing it) or try to
>   type the '.' while you have other digits after it.

Comment: It would be better if you show your code attempts so we can check whats problem you are facing. Without code its bit difficult.

Comment: I have updated the main post with the code as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did quite a bit of research and found no solution. So going with Option 3 - allow string input and handle it in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but I want to share the strange solution :)
Changing "**UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**" by "**UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus**" will allow decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in WPF App constructor add this code.

```cs
public App()
{
     FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences
          .KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
}
```

Or if using `Binding`, try adding `Delay` like 1 or 2 seconds. This will delay the validation before it kicks off.

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn
 Header="Age"
 Binding="{Binding Path=Age, Delay=1000,
           Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
           ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" >
```